# Why does svg opacity appear to change RGB values

Tags: html, svg, svg-filters

I am trying to understand how svg opacity is applied such that I can add transparency and subsequently remove it, and get the original image.

I have developed the following test case where I have 256 cells increasing in Red intensity.

The original has no opacity
I then add opacity using a script directly on each svg cell
I then use a filter to remove the opacity by removing the alpha channel

This third image should equal the first. It doesn't. When you look at the 1st and third boxes there is clearly a loss of resolution in the image that has the Alpha Channel removed.

This occurs in Chrome and Edge as shown in the picture below

[Cell color changed as a result of adding transparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXe7e.png)

Is it possible to have an arbitrary Alpha channel that can be added to an image and removed by a filter without changing the original image?

```js
        var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        var svg = document.getElementById("colormap");
        var cellSize = 10;
        var colCount = 16

                for (let r = 0; r < 256; r++) {
                    var cell = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
                    var x = (r % colCount)
                    var y = Math.trunc(r/colCount)
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x * cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y * cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "width", cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "height", cellSize);
                    
                    let Alpha = (r+1)/256


                    let hexColor = "#" + r.toString(16).padStart(2,"0") + "0000";
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "fill-opacity", Alpha);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", hexColor);
                    
                    svg.appendChild(cell);
                }

                var svg = document.getElementById("colormapNoAlpha");
                for (let r = 0; r < 256; r++) {
                    var cell = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
                    var x = (r % colCount)
                    var y = Math.trunc(r/colCount)
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x * cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y * cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "width", cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "height", cellSize);
                    
                    hexColor = "#" + r.toString(16).padStart(2,"0") + "0000";

                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", hexColor);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "fill-opacity", 1);
                    svg.appendChild(cell);
                }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Alpha Layers</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve"
             width="880" height="240"
             viewBox="0 0 880 240" >
      <defs>
            <!-- Pattern Definition -->
            <pattern id="checkerPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                    x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"
                    viewBox="0 0 10 10" >
                <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="0" stroke="lightblue" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="2,2" />
                <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="lightblue" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="2,2" />
                <rect x1="0" y1="0" width="20" height="20" stroke="lightblue" fill="black" stroke-dasharray="2,2" />
            </pattern>
          <!-- Filter Definition -->
        <g id="colormapNoAlpha"></g>  
        <g id="colormap"></g>
          <filter id="original" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" result="img2"
                type="matrix"
                values="1   0   0   0   0
                        0   1   0   0   0
                        0   0   1   0   0
                        0   0   0   1   0 "/>
          </filter>
        
          <filter id="removeAlpha" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" result="img2"
                type="matrix"
                values="1   0   0   0   0
                        0   1   0   0   0
                        0   0   1   0   0
                        0   0   0   0   1 "/>
          </filter>
          <filter id="selectAlpha" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" result="img2"
                type="matrix"
                values="0   0   0   1   0
                        0   0   0   1   0
                        0   0   0   1   0
                        0   0   0   0   1 "/>
          </filter>
        
          
      </defs>
      
      <!-- Background -->
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#checkerPattern)" />
     <!-- Result -->
        <g>
          
          <use x="020" y="020" id="in" xlink:href="#colormapNoAlpha"/>
          <use x="220" y="020" id="in" xlink:href="#colormap"/>
            
          <!-- filter="url(#removeAlpha)"   -->
          <use x="420" y="020" id="out1" xlink:href="#colormap" filter="url(#removeAlpha)" />
            
          <use x="640" y="020" id="out1" xlink:href="#colormap" filter="url(#selectAlpha)" />
          <text x="020" y="220" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="white">Original</text>
          <text x="220" y="220" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="white">Original Alpha</text>
          <text x="420" y="220" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="white">Remove Alpha</text>
          <text x="640" y="220" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="white">Only Alpha</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can confirm your result for Firefox/Linux. This is clearly an issue with rounding values as a result of transformation between sRGB and linearRGB color space. This happens for two operations: computing the filter values, and alpha compositing of colors into their background. The problem is, even after three hours of playing around with `color-interpolation` and `color-interpolation-filters` attributes, I have not found the point where this happens...